# Distribution of Java developed web application (Maven) to different platform independent users those who may not java on their system?

Tags: java, maven, model-view-controller

I am thinking a possible way to distribute a Java-based web application to users. The only solution I got is since I am using maven it is easier to package the project in a .war file and the users on the side needs a JSP/ Servlet containers to run that .war file. Is there any simpler way to distribute the .war file.

Also, I am using a MySQL database for storing the data. Then what happens to the database. How can only I will be the database owner without distributing the database? Do I need a server for that? Sorry for asking two questions.

Please let me know if the questions are not clear.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want to distribute your web application to multiple people who will deploy it themselves, but you want them all to use the same (your) database? That doesn't sound normal.

Comment: I guess what I meant is I managed to develop a Java MVC web application and can launch it on my local machine with the database I am using locally. Now I am thinking about how does I make that web application and database ready for commercial use. I am not as clear as of how to only show and capture the user's input and interacting with the database in real-time. So does that mean web hosting is for web application and database can be hosted in the different secure server? Sorry for all the confusion, I hope you are getting me what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a little peculiar to distribute a web application to users, since web application by definition should just accessible to users through the web, where you just deploy it yourself once however you want.

This also makes it much easier for users as it removes all the headaches of servlet containers and local server execution since users just need a web browser as well as eliminates the database problem you have.

Comment: Thanks makes sense :), As I can only see the website at my localhost so to make it visible to the users I need to focus on web hosting? I am getting it right? Thanks again for your input. Sorry for using the word distributing, it does not seem right word in this context.

Comment: Unless you internet service provider assigns a dedicated IP address (aka static IP) that is visible and reachable from WEB nobody outside your home network will be able to reach your app. Yes, the easiest way is to google web hosting options since you also won't need to always keep your home computer running.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable suggestion.